# Log a message in my terminal server (localhost:8000)

Tags: python, django

```
def clean_expired_requests():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    qs = Request.objects.filter(
            expires_at__date=now, state__in=[
                'documents', 'validation', 'evaluation', 'signature'])
    for req in qs:
        log.debug('Request %s expired' % req)
        req.expired_at_state = req.state.name
        req.save()
        req.expire()
        EmailFromTemplate('expired-request').send_to(req.customer.user)
```

I am working on a Django project. I would like to insert something which will advise me that the following method has been called when I run the server (`python manage.py runserver_plus`). I thought it could write me a message in my terminal server 'clean_expired_request has been called!'. How could I do such thing?

Please let me know if the question is unclear.

Comment: if you log it, and run with DEBUG=True you should see it in the logs

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Are you up to write a full answer with an example related to your comment. I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEBUG or change log level to info and it should appear in the standard log output

Comment: First of all, I bet that all of your conditions are supposed to be `if  'daily_game_schedule' in result and 'regular' in result:` and so on. As it stands now, it is not checked whether the first `str` is contained in `result`.

Comment: Yes thanks, you are right. Are you able to make that works fine?

Comment: Please don't overwrite your old questions, ask a new one. It makes all of the comments confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more Pythonic version of the code would separate out the logic from all of the `str`s. One solution is to store all of the pairs or `str`s and integers in a `dict`, like so:

```
def fix_nb_rows_per_table(url_ws, season_slug):
    result = url_ws + season_slug

    mapping = {('daily_game_schedule', 'regular'): 14,
               ('full_game_schedule', 'regular'): 1235,
               ...
               }
    for keys, val in mapping.items():
        if all(key in result for key in keys):
            return val
```